# Virtualbox causing weird behavior in Windows (keyboard issues, UAC popups)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, keyboard, 64-bit, uac

After installing Virtualbox, whenever I run it, my PC (Windows 7 x64 SP1) starts doing a few things that make it unusable until I restart the PC:

- Clicking a shortcut or other button on the taskbar (other than the Start button) brings up a UAC prompt asking if it's OK if the program makes changes to my computer.
- Typing on the keyboard is in all-caps no matter whether all-caps is on or off, and backspace deletes entire words instead of characters.
- Can't use Ctrl-Alt-Del to access task manager. Also can't right-click on the taskbar to start task manager, or use Alt-Tab to switch programs.

This behavior persists after Virtualbox Manager is closed.

I've installed several different versions of Virtualbox over the last year or so, this issue has been a problem for me in all of them, including the latest as I write this, v4.3.10. The problem occurs as soon as I run the main Virtualbox program (Virtualbox Manager), I haven't been able to even create a VM. I have run Virtualbox successfully on this machine in the past.

I've done various things to try to solve this, including:

- Reinstalling Windows from scratch, and installing vBox as my first piece of software.
- Installing vBox without its network drivers.
- Turning UAC off entirely (turns off the popups but I still can't use my taskbar).
- Uninstalling Microsoft Virtual PC (aka "XP Mode").
- Swapping in a different keyboard (my normal one has a bunch of non-standard keys).

I don't suppose anyone else has run into this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a problem with your keyboard? Because `Ctrl`+`Shift` clicking open's with admin rights, and of course `shift ` makes everything CAPS.

Comment: I don't think so, the problem only occurs when Virtualbox Manager is running. Everything is fine if vBox Manager is not running. That did occur to me though, I have a Kinesis Freestyle keyboard, which has a bunch of extra keys. I'll try swapping in a spare keyboard.